# Altering data source of PivotTable to second worksheet

Tags: excel, pivot, vba

I am creating a PivotTable using VBA code. I recorded my actions and was able to modify the code. The only problem is the actual data source set. The data is inside the `second worksheet` with a range of `A1 to T & LastRow`.

I tried to alter the data source with `Sheets(2)"A1:T" & LastRow`, but that failed.

```
ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:="august2015!R1C1:R734C20", Version:=xlPivotTableVersion10).CreatePivotTable TableDestination:="Sheet2!R1C1", TableName:="PivotTable3", DefaultVersion:=xlPivotTableVersion10
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to build up the address string, including the sheet name:

```
ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, _
    SourceData:="'" & Sheets(2).Name & "'!" & Range("A1:T" & lastrow).Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1), _
    Version:=xlPivotTableVersion10).CreatePivotTable _
    TableDestination:="Sheet2!R1C1", TableName:="PivotTable3", DefaultVersion:=xlPivotTableVersion10
```

FYI, for easier debugging I'd always suggest creating a pivotcache object, then creating a pivottable from that:

```
Dim pc                    As PivotCache
Dim pt                    As PivotTable
Set pc = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, _
        SourceData:="'" & Sheets(2).Name & "'!" & Range("A1:T" & lastrow).Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1), _
        Version:=xlPivotTableVersion10)
Set pt = pc.CreatePivotTable(TableDestination:="Sheet2!R1C1")
```

Comment: it throws me an invalid procedure or argument exception. Any suggestions?

Comment: Which version? And which line if the second version?

Comment: Both versions and on the ActiveWorkbook section.

Comment: Sorry - typo (I omitted a final apostrophe after the sheet name). Please try the revised version(s).

Comment: I just saw that too, but still generates same error :/

Comment: What's the value of `lastrow`? Do you have a sheet called Sheet2 and is there already a pivot table on it?

Comment: LastRow is populated correct, I don't have a sheet named `Sheet2`. My second sheet is named `august2015` (but next month it's september2015, etc).

Comment: If you don't have a sheet called Sheet2, you can't put the pivot table on it! You need to change the `TableDestination` argument.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention I had already corrected that :P It's exactly the same as the recording gave me, so I wouldn't know what's wrong either :/

Comment: Do you have valid headers in each cell in row 1? There can't be any blanks.

Comment: Yes, every column has valid headers

Comment: Can you put a sample file somewhere?

Comment: sure what do you need?

Comment: A workbook that demonstrates the error. Preferably with fake data. ;)

Comment: https://www.wetransfer.com/downloads/cb139f0e585226c86cfcc3bea4c8a00520150925084302/e5b9643ef9fd25f6ecfce488f455decc20150925084302/eb5b23

Comment: yeah :/ could it be something with the country settings?

Comment: What are your regional settings? Using the version that assigns a cache first then creates a pivot table, which step causes the error?

Comment: I am using Dutch (Belgium) settings. The step that causes the error is the ActiveWorkbook...., so the actual part to create the PivotTable

Comment: If you use the two step one, that line creates the cache, not the table. Are you using the two step code? Just changed my settings to match yours, and the code still works. Which version of Excel are you using?

Comment: I'm using Office 365 (2013)

Comment: I can't help you really - I tried in both 2010 and 2016 with your regional settings and no errors.

Comment: Hmmm strange :/ Well thank you for your time and effort! I'll have to look deeper.

Comment: is there a different way to call the Sheet? When I replace the `section Sheets(2).Name` and `Range("A1:T" & LastRow)` it passes

Comment: did some deeper investigation, it's 100% an issue with the variable Sourcedata :(

Comment: WHat does `msgbox "'" & Sheets(2).Name & "'!" & Range("A1:T" & lastrow).Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1)` show you?

Comment: Not sure, but I got it to work this using this: `ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=Sheets("august2015").Range("A1:T" & LastRow), Version:=xlPivotTableVersion10).CreatePivotTable TableDestination:="Master!R1C1", TableName:="PivotTable1", DefaultVersion:=xlPivotTableVersion10`. I temporarily change the worksheet name, it should work if I use a variable normally.